# How can I render a view from a predefined list/dict, instead of from a database id, in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm curious if I can render a view directly from a list (or dictionary) in Django instead of from a model, and thus programmatically generate pages based on the corresponding template (here, my_template.html). I've done this many times after creating a model whereby the `<str:my_list>` would reference the corresponding database in. In a use-case that involves an API call though, I'd rather not go the database route as it becomes somewhat redundant. I'm sure it has to be possible, but I seem to be going in circles trying to execute it.

urls.py

```
# ...

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path('path/<str:my_list>', views.my_view, name='my_view'),
]
```

views.py

```
# ...

def my_view(request, my_list):
    return render(request, 'core/my_template.html')
```

A list could be something as simple as:

```
my_list = [
    item_1,
    item_2,
    # ...
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you taken a look at contexts? I think you can easily pass arguments in the form of lists and dicts in a context to a template. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/api/

Comment: Absolutely. But I'm not just trying to pass the value from the context to the template, but rather render the view itself from the list.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the template is looking for a dictionary. In the template you reference the dictionary name and the key (I believe I am using the correct terms). If I wanted to access

```
my_list = {
   {'item_1':'cat'},
   {'item_2':'dog'},
   {'item_3':' el chupacabra'}
}
```

I would need to pass my list as context and reference in the template as:

```
{{ my_list.item_1 }}
{{ my_list.item_2 }}
{{ my_list.item_3 }}
```

However, you should be able to pass:

```
return render(request, 'core/my_template.html', {'item_1':'cat},{'item_2':'dog},{'item_3':' el chupacabra'})
```

and be able to get reference just the key in the template like this:

```
{{ item_1 }}
```

I am still relatively new to this, but these are the two ways that I have been able to get information to my templates.

Comment: Thanks for the attempted answer, but the question is how to create pages from a single template by using a list instead of calling an id from the database, not how to pass a value into the template.